# Create lags and moving average

Tags: r, lag, moving-average

I have a data frame that contains daily measurements of many meteorological and environmental variables. I need to create lags of 14 days and compute moving averages of 3 different consecutive lag  periods (lag 0 and 1, lag 2 to 6 and 8 to 14.  I would appreciate if someone would suggest a better and shorter method of doing the the task than shown below.

```
library(gamair) 
library(mgcv) 
data(chicago) 

attach(chicago)
m <- length(tmpd)
t <- 14
LAG_tmpd <- matrix(0,m,t)  

for (j in 1:t)         
{
  for (g in 1:j)      
  {
    LAG_tmpd[g,j]<-NA

  }
  for(i in (j+1):m)   
  {
    LAG_tmpd[i,j]<-c(tmpd[i-j])

  }
}
tmpd_lag01 <- (LAG_tmpd[,1]+LAG_tmpd[,2])/2
tmpd_lag26 <- (LAG_tmpd[,3]+LAG_tmpd[,4]+LAG_tmpd[,5]+LAG_tmpd[,6]+LAG_tmpd[,7])/5
tmpd_lag713 <- (LAG_tmpd[,8]+LAG_tmpd[,9]+LAG_tmpd[,10]+LAG_tmpd[,11]+LAG_tmpd[,12]+LAG_tmpd[,13]+LAG_tmpd[,14])/7
```

Comment: can you correct your code before please; **Error in LAG_tmpd[g, j] <- NA : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix**?

Comment: The code works fine on my PC and I don't get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replicate your results with the rather shorter

```
    m <- length(tmpd)
    lagmat <- matrix(rep(NA,m*14), nrow=m)
    for (i in 1:14){ lagmat[ (i+1):m, i] <- tmpd[1:(m-i)] }

    tmpd_lag01  <- rowMeans( lagmat[ , 1:2 ] )
    tmpd_lag26  <- rowMeans( lagmat[ , 3:7 ] )
    tmpd_lag713 <- rowMeans( lagmat[ , 8:14] )
```

Note that what you call `tmpd_lag01` in fact calculates the average of the valued lagged one period and lagged two periods, which I find slightly strange notation.  If this is not in fact what you want, and instead you want to include the most recent data in your moving average, then the initial code would become

```
    m <- length(tmpd)
    lagmat <- matrix(rep(NA,m*15), nrow=m)
    for (i in 1:15){ lagmat[ i:m, i] <- tmpd[1:(m-i+1)] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `filter`, for example:

```
f <- function(vec, lags) {
    weights <- rep(0, max(lags))
    weights[lags] <- 1
    filter(vec, filter=weights/length(lags), sides=1)
}

tmpd_lag26 <- f(tmpd, c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```